# How to increase the curl timeout in facebook php web-driver

Tags: php, facebook, selenium, curl, webdriver

I'm using **[facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver)** when I'm trying to connect to any website with a proxy using the following code  :

```
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);

try{
    $driver->navigate()->to("http://www.example.com/");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

It will take time because the proxy is sometimes slow then return the following error :

> Curl error thrown for http POST to /session/c189e325-9057-489c-b2de-93c95cdb1cc4/url with params: {"url":"http://www.live.com/"}
>
> Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received

**Question:** It's possible to increase the curl timedout delay **30001 milliseconds** ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`RemoteWebDriver::create()` supports specifying the connection and request timeout as the third and fourth arguments, e.g.

```
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create(
  $host,
  $capabilities,
  60 * 1000, // Connection timeout in miliseconds
  60 * 1000  // Request timeout in miliseconds
);
```

See: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/1.9.0/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php#L88